# Unable to launch in GAE

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to use the [codebase](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-cloudsql-native-mysql-hibernate-jpa-demo-java) to test connect a Google Cloud SQL instance with a GAE Application. I was able to run it successfully in local, but it seems that it gets deployed successfully also in AppEngine, but when I try to access myproject.appspot.com, I get a 404.

Following are the steps I followed (skipping the successful local related steps).

1. Created a project `myproject`
2. Created a Google Cloud SQL 2nd Generation instance, `myproject-db`
3. Created a `root` user with a password.
4. Used the connection string as indicated in Google Cloud Console `"jdbc:google:mysql://myproject:us-central1:myproject-db/demo?user=root&amp;password=PASSWORD;"`
5. appengine-web.xml looks like below

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
   <application>myproject</application>
   <version>1</version>
   <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
   <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>

   <system-properties>
   <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
   <property name="cloudsql.url" value="jdbc:google:mysql://myproject:us-central1:myproject-db/demo?user=root&amp;password=PASSWORD;"/>
   <property name="cloudsql.url.dev" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/demo?user=root&amp;useSSL=false"/>
   </system-properties>
   </appengine-web-app>
   ```
6. The following code snippet is embedded in HibernateJPAServlet

   ```
   if (System.getProperty("com.google.appengine.runtime.version")
               .startsWith("Google App Engine/")) {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
           properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver",
             "com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
           properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url",
             System.getProperty("cloudsql.url"));
       }
   ```
7. I've uploaded the code from my local to default myproject repository

   https://source.developers.google.com/p/myproject/r/default
8. I launched the Google Cloud Platform Console from the "Development" view.
9. Successfully ran `mvn clean package` and `mvn appengine:update`. I cannot perform a `appengine:update` from my local due to firewall/proxy restrictions.
10. So, at this point, my understanding is, I am running a GAE application and GAE Cloud SQL instance for the *same* project. So `http://myproject.appspot.com/` should host the application I uploaded Step 8. But when I access it says `"404" - "The requested URL / was not found on this server."`

Just in case the problem is we can't deploy it from Cloud Console, then what other alternative do I have? I absolutely can't change network/proxy rules.

### Edit

I tried running and deploying the application with `mvn gcloud:run` and `mvn gcloud:deploy` from outside proxy/firewall restrictions. At the end it clearly stated `"Deployed URL: [https://myproject.appspot.com]"`. But the same issue remains when I access the same Url through browser.

### Edit 2

I am able to see the error trace from App Engine dashboard. It is saying

```
" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost."
```

My connection string is "jdbc:google:mysql://myproject:us-central1:myproject-db/demo?user=root&password=PASSWD123&"

Comment: Where do you see this 404 error? In a log? In your browser?  Also, in step 8 you say you successfully ran `mvn appengine:update`, but then you say you cannot perform `appengine:update`. Which is it? Does that command succeed or fail?

Comment: Hi Eric, I can't do mvn appengine:update from my local... However I can do the same from Google Cloud Console, but after the deployment is over, when I try to access myproject.appspot.com through a browser, I see the 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my Bad (also partially Documentation gap and I've given feedback too). Everytime we deploy the app through `appengine` or `gcloud`, the newly deployed version should be visible through the `"App Engine > Versions"` Tab. We should `"Split Traffic"` and give `"100%"` (for testing) to the Newly deployed version and then launch "https://myproject.appspot.com" to see the results we want to see.